# Facebook Request Dialog API: Request or Invitation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Requests Dialog seem to generate two kinds of notification messages

1. Janet sent you requests in CityVille.
2. Janet have invited you to CityVille.

How does one specify which one to use. I couldn't find any options in

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: ''});
```

By default it seems to be generating message of type 1. App permission doesn't seem to effect this.

The legacy fb:request-form http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form  had options - 'invite' and 'type' to do exactly that.

How does one do the same thing using the Facebook Request Dialogs today ?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did you ever work out whether or not you could use the Requests dialog to send an invite?

Comment: Althought I haven't tried it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057553/facebook-request-dialog-api-request-or-invitation/12471488#12471488) might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the new API. It used to be possible earlier with the fb:friend:selector with invite=true.

Answer (score 3):

You may find this post useful:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/

And for request dialogs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, with the new Facebook 3.0 SDK this is automatic when you send a request to a user who hasn't installed your app yet.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/#invites

You just need to add

```
app_non_users
```

To your "filters" parameter